# using materialised views to fix bugs and reduce code

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

The application I'm working on has a legacy problem where 2 tables were created ADULT and CHILD in an oracle 11g dB. 
This has led to a number of related tables that have both a field for ADULT and CHILD no FK applied. 
The bugs have arisen where poor development has mapped relationships to the wrong  field.

Our technical architect plans to merge the ADULT and CHILD tables in to a new ADULT_CHILD table and create materialised views in place of the tables. The plan is to also create a new id value and replace the I'd values in all associated tables so even if the plsql/apex code maps to the wrong field the data mapping will still be correct.

The reasoning behind this solution it it does not require that we change any other code.

My opinion is this is a fudge but I'm more a Java/.NET OO.

What arguments can I use to convince the architect this is wrong and not a real solution. I'm concerned we are creating a more complex solution and performance will be an issue.

Thanks for any pointers

Comment: One of you two is wrong in your understanding of "materialised views" - they are just a snapshot of data at a given time. So unless you intend to update them continuously the data in them will be incorrect after the first update on the main table. You may as well use normal views - I don't see any reason not to.

Comment: The example looks like the MVs are updated when ever the source table is updated. Should I be concerned about performance.

Comment: What is the point in taking something that was designed for backup/replication/snapshot and attempting to use it (with difficulty) instead of standard views. What is the argument against the standard `view`? Update time is not going to be worse than trying to replicate the updated data, query time will again be not worse if you had required indexes on the main table. So, why not?

Comment: Highly related http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/78100/how-do-i-tell-a-senior-programmer-that-i-disagree-with-him, I thought that this question had a quote I was looking for but I can't find it. Basically, maybe he knows something that you don't. You don't give anywhere near enough information about the topic. There might be monetary/project limits that you are not aware of.

Answer (score 1):

While it may be a needed solution it might also create new issues. If you really do need to use an MV that is up to date at all times, you need on commit refresh and that in turn tends to make all updates sequential. Meaning that all processes writing to it waits in line for the one updating the table to commit. Not, the table, not the row.

So it is prudent to test the approach with realistic loads. Why does it have to become a single table? Could they not stay separate, add a FK? If you need more control on the updates, rename them and put views with instead-of triggers in their place.